# Jquery stars and "If then" button link

Tags: javascript, jquery, rating

My jquery/java skills are non-existant.... I need some quick help:

My boss wants to have a form where customers write a review and stars for discounts then hit submit; if they select more than 3 stars it takes them to a separate page than someone who submitted a review with less stars.

Is it possible to have a j query button that changes the link on the fly depending on stars chosen?

I'm using the j query Star-rating plugin:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/rating.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/rating.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Rating CSS">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('.container').rating();
        });


    </script>
</head>

<body>

<h1><a title="Full Documentation" href="http://irfandurmus.com/projects/jquery-star-rating-plugin/">jQuery Star Rating Plugin</a></h1>

    <section class="container">
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="1" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="2" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="3" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="4" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="5" />
    </section>

<script type="text/javascript">
if  $('.container').rating(4,5) {
    echo "<a href="eventual link> Click here to receive your discount code</a>" ;
}
else $('.container').rating(1,2,3) {
    echo "<a href="eventual link>Click here to recieve your discount code</a>";
}
   </script>
```

Comment: You _need_ to learn Javascript.  You cannot simply write random code that looks like what you want and expect it to work.

Comment: there's probably a callback function that fires when the rating is submitted. use that to check the rating and forward with javascript.

Comment: Side note: please tell me you are not using w3school.com to learn how to code. I ask because of the `<section>` tag.

Comment: After you submit, what happens?  Does it AJAX post the form?  Is there even a form in question here?  Does the form post back to a page?  If so, why not have that page redirect to a different discount page?  Your question is hard to follow.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.container').rating({
     callback: function(value){
          if(value > 3){
               $('.container').after('<a href="eventual link"> Click here to receive your discount code</a>');
          }else{
               $('.container').after('<a href="eventual link"> Click here to receive your discount code</a>');
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: On each subsequent rating change, won't this add more and more links?

Comment: Yes, but this is a solution to check, I will not worry about all the details of the program.

Comment: Makes sense.  Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function `onClick()`, attach it to the submit button (or whatever element you want), and then inside the method say

```
if (stars >= 3) {
 window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/goodratingpage'
} else
 window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/badratingpage'
}
```

The `window.location` (as you may have guessed) just redirects the user to another page.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer from this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547120/jquery-star-rating-plugin-and-jquery-click-function) you can attach a callback to the click event of the star rating.

```
$('.container').rating({ 
  callback: function(value, link){ 
     if (value > 3)
        window.location.href = "http://example.org";
     else
        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  } 
});
```